# Importing into 2013 from 2010 export.cmp files

Tags: import

I have export.cmp files from a SharePoint 2010 environment outside my company. Is it possible to import them into a 2013 test environment I have setup?

I have done a lot of fooling around with Import-SPWeb, and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to just export and import content from Sharepoint 2010 to a Sharepoint 2013 environment. ( If you still have access to the 2010 environment, there is 3rd party tools available for moving stuff from 2010 to 2013. )

What you can do however is to restore the files to a SharePoint 2010 environment, and then take a backup of the content database and upgrade it to 2013.

This blogpost gives you 2 options, one is modifying the cpm files and then restore them to Sharepoint 2013. ( Not supported by Microsoft. )

The other one is going with the database upgrade and is the only way to move and upgrade content that is supported by Microsoft.

**The blogpost subject is moving a list, but modifying the cmp file for a site should be very much the same.**

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Looks great. I will use one of these methods. J